# Dovecot Virtual domain/passwd-file login issue

Tags: dovecot, passwd, email

I used this walk through http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/VirtualUserFlatFilesPostfix but there is still an issue not allowing me to login.

/var/log/dovecot.log

```
Jan 13 10:25:49 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<test@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.180.34.84, lip=10.180.33.42
Jan 13 10:49:14 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (auth failed, 2 attempts): user=<test@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.180.34.84, lip=10.180.33.42
Jan 13 10:49:19 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<test@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.180.34.84, lip=10.180.33.42
```

I have disabled selinux and debuggin is enabled but still not able to get logged in

```
dovecot -n
# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_plugins = acl quota
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress             comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify     environment mailbox date
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  prefix =
  separator = /
  type = private
}
namespace {
  list = yes
  location = maildir:/var/vmail/prodmail:INDEX=~/Maildir/public:LAYOUT=fs:INDEX=~/public
  prefix = prodmail/
  separator = /
  subscriptions = no
  type = public
}
passdb {
  args = username_format=%u /var/vmail/auth.d/%d/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
  sieve_global_dir = /var/vmail/conf.d/%d/sieve
}
protocols = imap lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = dovecot
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    address = 10.180.33.42
    port = 143
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = no
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/crt.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/certs/key.pem
userdb {
  args = username_format=%u /var/vmail/auth.d/%d/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
verbose_proctitle = yes
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = acl quota sieve
  postmaster_address = root@domain.com
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = acl quota imap_acl imap_quota mail_log notify
}

cat /var/vmail/auth.d/domain.com/passwd
test@domain.com:{SSHA}f/u4RU+tYRQL3dhQcw3FHnscxcABOg8D:999:999:/var/vmail/domain.com/test/
test:{SSHA}f/u4RU+tYRQL3dhQcw3FHnscxcABOg8D:999:999:/var/vmail/domain.com/test/
```

there was an issue with the guide to use the user doveauth which does not exist so i switched that to use dovecot user.

```
[root@ vmail]# ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxrwx.  4 vmail   vmail   4096 Jan 12 15:10 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root    root    4096 Jan 12 11:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  3 dovecot dovecot 4096 Jan 12 11:16 auth.d
drwxr-xr-x.  3 vmail   vmail   4096 Jan 12 15:09 domain.com
[root@ vmail]#
```

Comment: Maybe your auth.d folder must have `dr-x------` permission, as the wiki said.

Comment: I wouldn't think that having more than required would cause an issue. Or at least it would throw an error saying so.

Comment: Could you please enable `auth_debug` and `auth_verbose`? It may produce more detailed log.